# discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found

Tags: python, discord.py

so i was trying to create my first discord bot, with no experience in Python whatsoever just to learn stuff by doing so and stumbled on an Error (Title) which was answered quiet a lot, but didn't really help me.

Im just gonna share my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="=", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is connected to Discord")

@commands.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")

    client.add_command(ping)

@client.command()
async def magic8ball(ctx, *, question):
    with open("Discordbot_rank\magicball.txt", "r") as f:
        random_responses = f.readlines()
        response = random.choice(random_responses)

    await ctx.send(response)

    client.add_command(magic8ball)

client.run(Token)
```

I tried to run this multiple times, first without the client.add_command line, but both methods for registering a command didn't work for me. I also turned all options for privileged gateway intents in the discord developer portal on. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an incorrect decorator for your command `ping`. It should be `@client.command()` in your case.
Also, in most of the cases, you don't need to call `client.add_command(...)` since you use the `command()` decorator shortcut already.
Only when you have [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html#ext-commands-cogs), you will use `@commands.command()` decorator. Otherwise, all commands in your main py file should have decorator `@client.command()` in your case. 
A little bit of suggestion, since you already uses `commands.Bot`, you could rename your `client` variable to `bot` since it is a little bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Slash commands cause user commands are no longer available

Example code using [Pycord](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord) library

```
import discord

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.slash_command()
async def hello(ctx, name: str = None):
    name = name or ctx.author.name
    await ctx.respond(f"Hello {name}!")

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: Tried that one out, didn't change anything for me

    @client.slash.command()
    async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")